# The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable - Translation Manager

Tags: translation-manager, worldserver

I am configuring the translation manager on Tridion 2013 (New Server) and getting below error messages.

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source Translation Manager cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.

StackTrace Information Details:
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Com.Idiominc.Webservices.Data.WSContextService.loginUser(String userName, String password)
   at Com.Idiominc.Webservices.Client.WSContext.loginUser(String userName, String password)
   at Com.Idiominc.Webservices.Client.WSContext.login(String userName, String password)
   at Com.Idiominc.Webservices.Client.WSContext..ctor(String user, String password, String serverURL)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerConfiguration.GetWSContext()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerConfiguration.GetWSWorkflowManager()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationSystems.WorldServerConfiguration.PurgeCachedWorkflowsNoLongerAvailable(UserContext userContext)
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.TranslationJobManager.PerformDailyCleanup()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.SendForTranslationTask.Process()
   at Tridion.TranslationManager.DomainModel.Service.ServiceTask.ThreadMethod()

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

And Second point - We are getting "**The Selected Items cannot be combined into a single Translation Job**" when clicking on the "Translate" link

Are we missing any configurations?

What we tried:

1. Verified the configurations with the Tridion 2011 setup
2. Checked the WorldServer url access
3. Verified the SQL database connection

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 503 response indicates that the service is temporarily unavailable. So it may be overloaded at the times when it gives this message, but working correctly when you manually check the URL. I'd suggest you look into the server logs of the service which is returning the 503 status.